# SQL Merge/Group lines into a single one

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I would like to know what is the most optimized SQL for this problem.
I have to apply a SQL query on a table which contains invalid data in order to correct all those invalid data.
The table is structured like below :

```
TABLE(customer_id, start_date, end_date, type)
```

Currently, the table can contain many lines for a given tuple (customer_id,type).
My query needs to "merge" all line belonging to a group into a single one and keep the most recent date for start date and the oldest for end date :

```
Cust1;01/01/2012;01/01/2020;1
Cust1;01/01/2010;01/01/2024;1
```

should transform into a single line

```
Cust1;01/01/2012;01/01/2024;1
```

I **need to correct the data not only select it** : delete lines if there is more than 1 and retrieve datas from each ! 
I hope my explanations are clear enough !
I work with Oracle DBMS

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `max()` function

```
    select customer_id,type, max(start_date),max(end_date)
    from t1
    group by customer_id,type
```

i think you want create another table by using these data

```
 create table test_t as
 select customer_id,type, max(start_date),max(end_date)
        from t1
        group by customer_id,type
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, but I need to correct the data from the table. Not only get the correct result !

Comment: So I can't avoid copy ? Thanks anyway

Comment: @LostReality for sure you **can avoid copy** - see alternative answer

Answer (score 1):

Do the aggregation :

```
select customer_id, max(start_date), max(end_date), type
from table t
group by customer_id, type;
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, but I need to correct the data from the table. Not only get the correct result !

Comment: @LostReality. . . Then copy the data into other table using this query & do truncate operation on old table.

Comment: and then simply apply "insert into select" ? good & simple idea. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have only small number of duplicated row an alternative approch using in place update / delete will be prefereble.

So first check the number of duplicated rows

```
with clean as (
select CUSTOMER_ID, TYPE, max(start_date) start_date_clean, max(end_date)  end_date_clean
from tab group by CUSTOMER_ID, TYPE)
select tab.*, start_date_clean, end_date_clean
from tab join clean on tab.CUSTOMER_ID = clean.CUSTOMER_ID and tab.TYPE = clean.TYPE
where  start_date != start_date_clean or  end_date != end_date_clean
;
```

This query will return all rows that will be processed, i.e. either start or end date are not correct.

If this number is large - go the way as proposed by other answer - copy the table and replace the original table with the copy.

If the **number is small*, go the `update` / `delete`  way:

```
update tab a
set a.START_DATE = (select max(b.START_DATE) from tab b where a.customer_id = b.customer_id and a.type = b.type),
a.END_DATE = (select max(b.END_DATE) from tab b where a.customer_id = b.customer_id and a.type = b.type)
where (a.customer_id, a.type) in 
( 
select tab.CUSTOMER_ID, tab.TYPE 
from tab join 
(select CUSTOMER_ID, TYPE, max(start_date) start_date_clean, max(end_date)  end_date_clean
from tab group by CUSTOMER_ID, TYPE) clean 
on tab.CUSTOMER_ID = clean.CUSTOMER_ID and tab.TYPE = clean.TYPE
where  start_date != start_date_clean or  end_date != end_date_clean);
```

This updates in all affected rows the `start` and `end` date to the correct vales.

example

```
CUSTOMER_ID START_DATE          END_DATE                  TYPE
----------- ------------------- ------------------- ----------
          1 01-01-2013 00:00:00 01-01-2016 00:00:00          1 
          1 01-01-2012 00:00:00 01-01-2018 00:00:00          1 
          1 01-01-2010 00:00:00 01-01-2017 00:00:00          1 
          2 01-01-2010 00:00:00 01-01-2018 00:00:00          1 
          3 01-01-2010 00:00:00 01-01-2018 00:00:00          1
```

is updated to

```
CUSTOMER_ID START_DATE          END_DATE                  TYPE
----------- ------------------- ------------------- ----------
          1 01-01-2013 00:00:00 01-01-2018 00:00:00          1 
          1 01-01-2013 00:00:00 01-01-2018 00:00:00          1 
          1 01-01-2013 00:00:00 01-01-2018 00:00:00          1 
          2 01-01-2010 00:00:00 01-01-2018 00:00:00          1 
          3 01-01-2010 00:00:00 01-01-2018 00:00:00          1
```

In the next step the duplicated rows must be deleted. This makes the next delete which user the `ROW_NUMBER` to identify the duplicates:

```
delete from tab where rowid in 
(select RID from (
  select rowid rid,
  row_number() over (partition by CUSTOMER_ID, TYPE order by null) rn
  from tab) 
where rn > 1)
;
```

What you see - the *brute force*  copy approach is simple in queries, but leaves the table offline for some time. You need twice as space to perform it and it will take some time.

The *update* approach is more complicated, but goes without maintainance window and is quickly done.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer ! It helps me a lot.